# php, how to get the keywords out of an url?

Tags: php, mysql

the question might be a bit confusing, so here is what i have:

i insert in the database the previous link where a person came from like tihs:

```
$came_from = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; // get previous link
```

if the link is from google.com it will come like this:

```
http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=this+is+a+test&pbx=1&oq=this+is+a+teat&aq=f&aqi=g-s1g-v1&aql=1&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=887l82702l3.10.3.1l17l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=c3d3303&biw=1920&bih=995
```

if we look inside we can find `q=this+is+a+test`as beeing the keywords that i search for.

my question is how can i create a query to return `http://www.google.com/ | this+is+a+test` ?

i know that the keywords have the `+` sign in between them.

so far i came up with this, but not exactly what i wanted:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX (table, '+', 1), table FROM table.table WHERE table LIKE '%+%' LIMIT 20
```

any ideas?

thanks

edit: what happend is that sometimes i get some other url's that don't have `q=` but maybe `seearch=`, so i want to keep track of the `+` sign

Comment: The first problem I see with your approach is that it will fail if the search string is a single word. BTW, how do you plan to get it without relying `q=`?

Comment: And i still don't get why won't you use something like Regexp, that way you can look for both `q=` and `seearch=` and any other key you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's been pointed out, you can't reliably get the keywords without supplying the parameters to look for. Here's what I would do:

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=this+is+a+test&pbx=1&oq=this+is+a+teat&aq=f&aqi=g-s1g-v1&aql=1&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=887l82702l3.10.3.1l17l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=c3d3303&biw=1920&bih=995';

$possible = array('q', 'ssearch', 'oq');

$query_str = NULL;
foreach ($possible as $search) {
    if (isset($arr[$search])) {
        $query_str = $arr[$search];
        break;
    }
}
```

Basically all this does is parse the url using PHP's [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and look for the parameter q. If it's not there, it uses ssearch, and then oq. You can add more of them if you need to. If by the end of it it's not found, $query_str will be NULL.

---

Unless you have a very compelling reason to do it with MySQL only, just process everything on the PHP side. Databases are made to store data, not process it. What I would do is have PHP figure out the search engine and the keywords used and insert those into the DB, as separate fields. ie, have a table like so:

```
search_engine | query_str
------------- | -----------
google        | test
yahoo         | something
...
```

Comment: nope, that won't help me much, i am looking for a mysql query

Comment: @Patrio While I won't say that it's impossible to do it with mysql, it would be unnecessarily complex and probably unreliable. *Why* would you want a mysql only query?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you need q=... then you can use regexp. I will update post if that's what you need.

Comment: i know , but i don't want to use `q=`

Comment: So basically you want to look for a value of certain key, without giving key (in this case q) ?

Comment: You can't, the `+` means a space (encoded), if the values don't contain any spaces, there will be no `+`!

Comment: as i see they are separators, thus you can get q and oq. From your post edit, i see that there may be other urls. so why not using OR operator in WHERE clause ? `WHERE ... REGEXP ... OR ... LIKE ...` Something like that.

Comment: well, i have a lot of records coming from multiple search engines and i cant go and sort through all of them manually

Comment: @Patriot Yet another reason why this shouldn't be done with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone is saying, you need to use the key value (in your example, `q`). In MySQL, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(table, '?q=', -1), table FROM table.table WHERE table LIKE '?' LIMIT 20
```

I'd also suggest you rename your table column to something other than 'table'.

Comment: This doesn't quite work, because it will include extra, unnecessary stuff. I would process this on the application side.

Comment: thanks, but i really need not to use the q= , i need to keep track only of the + sign

Comment: As everyone is saying `+` sign is encoding stuff for WHITESPACE, therefore, if there will not be any spaces, your query will not return needed urls (row will not be included)

Comment: @NullUserExeption, Yes, I agree this should be done on the server side. I'm just offering a SQL query that will do what he is asking, for thet specific example he gave, and in SQL as he requested. Anyway, if he doesn't quit insisting on using `+`, no answer will be good enough.